# How to integrate GooglePay to Big Commerce store using Authorize.net as payment gateway?

Tags: bigcommerce, authorize.net, google-pay

I want to integrate GooglePay to my BigCommerce Store.
I'm using Authorize.net as a payment gateway.

I had a chance to research if it's possible, but from those links below I wonder if it's impossible.

https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/Google-Pay-integration-with-Authorize-net/td-p/61667
https://developers.google.com/pay/api/#participating-processors

They say "Authorize.net is not supporting GooglePay"

I'm wondering because auth.net supports GooglePay and there's even a setting in auth.net to setup GooglePay.
So I'm wondering if I can customize BigCommerce to implement it.

Please let me know if it's possible or not, and if possible please help me to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Authorize.Net is on the [Google Pay's list of supported PSPs](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/#participating-processors) and contains a link to [Authorize.Net's developer site](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/in-app.html#Google_Pay).

BigCommerce has an [article on Google Pay integration](https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/article/Connecting-with-Google-Pay) however, I don't know if this extends to also include Authorize.Net. You may have to reach out to Authorize.Net or BigCommerce for more information.